# Python regex findall() substrings between single apostrophes

Tags: python, regex, nlp, substring, findall

So I need to capture substrings in a string that are in between two single apostrophes.

For this example I have string:

> the real question this movie poses is not 'who ? ' but 'why ? '

The output I am currently getting is:
[[" 'who ? ' "], [], []]

I would like for the regex to capture 'why ? ' as well but I do not know why it is not working.

This is my regex

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(\s+[\']{1}\D{2,}[^\']+[\']{1} | ^[\']{1}\D{2,}[^\']+[\']{1}$)")
```

The reason I have the \D is that I do not want to capture say '70s and I need at least 2 characters because I do not want the capture the 'n in rock 'n roll. 
I figured to add [^\'] because before it was capturing the full 
'who ? ' but 'why ? '
but instead I need 
'who ? ' and 
'why ?' 
to be separate matches. 
Any advice will help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r"(?<!\S)'([^\d\s']{2,}[^']*)'", text)` if you want to extract strings inside single quotes with at least two chars with the first two not being digits and whitespaces. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQIXI8/24).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks that worked!

Comment: good question, but you should update your test string with the '70 thing and rock'n roll because else the test string isn't representative of what you want.

Comment: @ChelseyW I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57998885/3832970). If you have more test cases please update the question and let those who answered know via comments under the answers. It seems possible that you will need to make the pattern a bit more precise, just make sure you share the exact requirements.

Answer (score 2):

to avoid special cases easily, I'd suggest some pre-processing to make the regular expression easier.

First remove the strings like `'70` or `'n` (followed by space), then it's easy with non-greedy match between simple quotes.

I have changed the input string to introduce a 'digit and rock 'n roll.

```
import re

s = "the real question this '70 rock 'n roll movie poses is not 'who ? ' but 'why ? '"

s = re.sub(r"'(\d+|\w\s)","",s)

print(re.findall("'.*?'",s))
```

prints:

```
["'who ? '", "'why ? '"]
```

If you have more counter examples, it's much easier to remove them using a similar replacement technique rather than trying not to match them.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
re.findall(r"(?<!\S)'([^\d\s']{2,}[^']*)'", text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQIXI8/2)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - whitespace or start of string should be right before
- `'` - a `'` char
- `([^\d\s']{2,}[^']*)` - Group 1: 2 or more chars other than digit, whitespaces and single quotes, and then any 0+ chars other than `'`
- `'` - a `'` char.